# Intellij Debug Mockito mock(interface) Test - NullpointerException

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test

Test class code:

```
when(sqlSession.getMapper(ArgumentMatchers.eq(AlertSignalMstMapper.class))).thenReturn(alertSignalMstMapper);
```

Here AlertSignalMstMapper is an interface.

When I do >mvn test
the tests passes.

But when I used debug of Intellij I get null on the actual class (And not in test method):

```
 List<AlertSignalMst> alertSigMsts = sqlSession.getMapper(AlertSignalMstMapper.class).getMstCodes();
```

Here sqlSession.getMapper(AlertSignalMstMapper.class) returns null on actuall class to be tested.

This line returns the mock object when the jupiter Test class (import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
) is used instead of import org.junit.Test;

Not sure if this is an intellij issue or I am not setting mockito correctly. I am usingh Java17, maven, Spring boot, Mockito 4.5, Junit 4.13.2

Comment: Could you share your test class code? Looks like invalid usage of setup annotations - they've changed between JUnit 4 and 5, same with annotations registering runner/extension on the test classes.